# TensorFlow Federated - How to work with SparseTensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am using TensorFlow Federated to simulate a scenario in which clients hosted on a remote server can work with our very sparse dataset in a federated setting.

Presently, the code is capable of running with a small subset of the very sparse dataset being loaded on the server-side and passing it to the remote workers hosted on another device. The data is in SVM Light format and can be loaded through sklearn's *load_svmlight_file* function, but needs to be converted into Tensors to work within tff. The current solution to do so involves converting the very sparse data into a dense array, then setting it up through the *tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices* function for use with a keras model (following existing examples for tff).

This works, but takes up significant memory resources and is not suitable for the dataset as it cannot be run remotely for more than six samples due to the sparse data's serialized size, nor locally with more than a few hundred samples due to the size in memory.

To mitigate this, I converted the data into SparseTensors, but this approach fails due to the *tff.learning.from_keras_model* function expecting a pair of TensorSpec input_spec values, not a SparseTensorSpec input_spec with the labels being TensorSpec.

So, are there any concrete examples or known methods to work with SparseTensors within keras models in tff? Or must they be as Tensors for now? The data loads fine when not converted to regular Tensors so I will need to find a solution for working with the sparse data.

If there is presently no way to do so, are there examples of strategies within tff to work with very small subsets of data at a time, either being loaded directly with the remote client or being passed from the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best approach now is to work with the TF's representation of `tf.SparseTensor`. That is, a tuple of 3 tensors, `indices`, `values` and `dense_shape`.

So when the problem is with Keras requiring the input to not be sparse tensors, you can pass in the input as for instance a dictionary consisting of these three tensors, which you convert to `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` as part of your `tf.data` pipeline.

See also [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/sparse_federated_learning) which I think is doing something related to what you are looking for, and please ask more detailed questions if needed!